# parse pdf file and conversion

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf

i try to edit pdf file and generate other pdf file.
the problem that this conversion not work.
it mean i can save pdf file in the document but it is empty file

```
aData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSArray *documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

// This should be our documents directory
NSString *saveDirectory = [documentPath objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *str=[self convertNsdataToString:nsdata];


//str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<<" withString:@"chikos"];
NSData* aData;
aData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//writing the pdf converted in the memory at path

NSString *saveDirectory2 = [saveDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.pdf"] ;
[aData writeToFile:saveDirectory2 atomically:YES];
```

Comment: "not work perfect" = ?????  To make this a better question, could you edit your original question to explain *WHAT* the problem is, how it doesn't work perfect or if there's an error, what that error is?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just do a search and replace on text data in a PDF file. It is not structured like that. You need to parse the content streams (which can be compressed/encrypted) to see what s going on.

Comment: Well, the bigger problem is that iOS comes with no support for writing the objects that you get when you parse the content stream....

Comment: tany solution to parse pdf file?  i just want get the object